# Poset of sub-graphs up to isomorphism

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I'm given the question

> Draw the Hasse diagram of the partially-ordered set of of connected subgraphs, up to isomorphism, of the graph $K_{2,1}$ ordered by containment.
>   Show that if the qualifier "up to isomorphism" is removed, then the resulting partially ordered set is not a lattice."

I understand the first part well enough. I just create a poset of the 5 non-isomorphic subgraphs and then draw the Hasse diagram with an $\{0\}$ at the bottom and the graph $K_{2,1}$ at the top.

I'm confused about the second part however. Wouldn't any pair of subgraphs of $K_{2,1}$ in a Hasse diagram share the upperbound $K_{2,1}$ and lower bound $\{0\}$?

Comment: How do you get $5$ connected subgraphs up to isomorphism? I only see $3$ of them: $K_1,\ K_2,$ and $K_{2,1}.$ Okay, $4$ if you count the null graph (no vertices).

Comment: For a lattice, it's not enough to show that every pair of elements has an upper bound and a lower bound; every pair needs a **least** upper bound and a **greatest** lower bound. I don't know what $\{0\}$ is supposed to mean here; is $0$ one of the three vertices of $K_{2,1}?$

Comment: I mistakenly put unconnected subgraphs which led me to more than I should have. $\{0\}$ was supposed to represent the null set. Would the null set and $K_{2,1}$ not be the greatest lower bound and least upper bound of any isomorphic subgraph?